# Can I use systemd-homed with 20.04?

Tags: gnome, systemd, home-directory, 20.04

I see that Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa was released with [Systemd 245](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/systemd), which supports [systemd-homed](https://systemd.io/HOME_DIRECTORY/). Has someone already tried using it? Preferably with LUKS? Is it setup during installation or what steps are required?

Answer (score 5):

As we read in the systemd [documentation](https://systemd.io/HOME_DIRECTORY/) the homed files should be available under `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-homed`. That directory is missing in the latest release of systemd for Ubuntu focal ([245.4-4ubuntu3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/systemd)).

I assume homed was not included in the LTS release as it is a major change and LTS releases prioritize stability over features.

If you wish, you may compile your own version of systemd from source (**not recommended**).

If doing so I would recommend looking into these guides from a user on Arch Linux:

https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/fgc91b/with_systemd_245_landing_in_repos_systemdhomed_is/

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-homed

**Update:** *As of Ubuntu 21.10 systemd-homed is still not available.*

**Update 2:** *As of Ubuntu 22.04 systemd-homed is still not available.*

**Update 3:** *`systemd-homed` is now available in 22.10! I'll be trying to move my 'old' home folder to the new system and update the post*

Comment: Do you know if it's available in Ubuntu 20.10+?

Comment: No, it hasn't been added yet. I'd expect it to land in 21.10 so it can be tested before the next LTS 22.04. But we'll see if the devs decide it's worth it to add it before the LTS release or put it off to after that.

Comment: It's still unavailable in 22.04. From what I understand it will be [a part of 22.10 Kinetic Kudu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/systemd-homed) release. Does it mean that it can be expected to appear in 24.04 LTS at the earliest?

Comment: If it is added to 22.10 then indeed I would expect it to also be available in the next LTS release, which would be 24.04 as you mentioned.